# Dropnet web service download file

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, dropnet

I'm developing a web service using WCF. This web service use JSON to communicate with the clients. Furthermore it provides several methods using the DropNet API.
Now I need to download a file, so I created a method called DownloadFile(...). What should I do to return the file using JSON?
The DropNet method: GetFile(string path) returns a byte array, after calling this method how can i return the file to the client??
I hope it's all clear.
Thank you

At the moment my method return a shared url:

```
public string DownloadFile(UserCredential data)
    {
        DropNetClient _client = new DropNetClient(data.appKey, data.appSecret);

        _client.UserLogin = new UserLogin() { Token = data.token, Secret = data.secret };

        var file = _client.GetShare(data.root);
        return file.Url;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do such as save the file to disk then download it etc.

But I prefer the semi-hack to download directly from Dropbox.
Get the Share Url and add a query string parameter dl=1 to the url and that should trigger a direct download on that url.